# Reducing the size of greek letters in TeX Gyre Schola Math?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, tex-gyre-math

I've been experimenting with TeX Gyre Schola (and its math font), and I've noticed that the greek letters are noticeably larger than normal letters and numbers.  For example, consider the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}

\begin{document}

\[
\phi = \tan^{-1} 2\theta
\]

\end{document}
```

This yields the following:

[image: Big theta in TeX Gyre Schola]

where the the theta appears to me as abnormally large.  Theta is the most noticeable to me (so far), but some of the other greek letters are also a bit larger than I'd expect.  Contrast this with what is obtained with Latin Modern (Math):

[image: Normal sized theta in Latin Modern]

Here, the height of the theta is not so much more than than height of the numbers or letters.

My question is therefore the following: Is there a way to reduce the size of the greek characters in the Schola math font? Or am I doing something wrong (or not doing something I ought to)?

Comment: Just a quick note, from the [README](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/download/readme-tex-gyre-schola-math.txt/view): "Greek symbols are based on Theano Modern font".

Comment: @morbusg, thanks I hadn't noticed that... I guess that explains why the weighting looks a little different from the other characters as well.

Comment: Choosing that model for the Greek letter is disputable: the x-height corresponds, but letters with ascenders become too high. Limiting the height with `\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{greek,Greek},Scale=0.85]{Tex Gyre Schola Math}` makes a good height for theta, but bad for alpha. Also the stroke width is too different.

Comment: @egreg, do you know of a math font that might be better suited to Schola?

Comment: Perhaps `\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{greek}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`; however, uppercase Greek is bad anyway (the letters are the same as in Termes Math). My impression is that Schola Math has been released with too much haste.

Comment: One should really need to understand what a massive undertaking it is to produce a comprehensive math OTF. [GUST goes to even say that](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/math/index_html) "However, in contrast to the Latin Modern and Latin Modern Math fonts, it is impossible to typeset “real” mathematical papers using only TeX Gyre fonts, because so far math symbols are scarcely represented. The available symbols should suffice for typesetting of technical texts but not for “strictly mathematical” papers."

Comment: @morbusg This doesn't justify choosing clashing fonts for Greek.

Comment: @egreg: Maybe they're going by "release early, release often". I wouldn't want to discourage their work. Anyhow, speaking of clashing fonts, I'm not sure Termes Math fits so well; maybe try Bonum Math?

Comment: @morbusg I don't want to discourage their work either. But I can comment on the result. The Greek lowercase chosen for Bonum are simply ugly; and the uppercase are the same as in Termes.

Comment: @morbusg, Bonum math for the example above looks ok to me.  Just out of curiosity, though, can I scale theta down, like @egreg did earlier... but only for theta (or other characters as needed)?  The `unicode-math` manual seems to indicate yes, but using `range=\theta` doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to use Latin Modern Math, but "thicken" it to have a similar weight?  I notice that FakeBold didn't work with luaLaTeX.

Comment: @Tyler: I don't know enough about `unicode-math` to answer your question, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Greek lowercase letter chosen for TeX Gyre Schola Math are, in my opinion, not matching the main font: they are too thin and, of course, some of them are too tall.

You have some strategies available. First, scaling down all the Greek lowercase letters:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
%%% Scale down!
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/greek,Scale=.8]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
%%% Circumvent a bug in unicode-math
\setmathfont[range=\int]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}

\begin{document}

\[
\phi = \tan^{-1} 2\theta
\]
\[
a\alpha\beta\gamma c
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This has the defect that the alpha becomes too small.

Second strategy: scale down only the letters that are too tall: change the code above into

```
%%% Scale down!
\setmathfont[range={\mittheta,\mitbeta},Scale=.8]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
```

[image]

You'll have to augment the list with the letters you want to use and scale down.

Third: use XITS Math or another font for Greek:

```
%%% Scale down!
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/greek,Scale=MatchLowercase]{XITS Math}
```

[image]