# Changing the size of the mathfont, except for the numbers

Tags: luatex, fontspec, fontsize, unicode-math, math-fonts

I need to use Tex Gyre Adventor as a font in my documents. This font has no math font, so I'd like to use the numbers of that font in math mode.
I managed to do it using `\setmathfont[range=up/{num}]{TeX Gyre Adventor}`, as indicated in the documentation of unicode-math.

My problem is that the numbers in math mode are bigger than the letters. Here is below an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\setmathfont{xits-math}
\setmathfont[range=up/{num}]{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\begin{document}
In text mode: 3\,z.

In math mode: $3\,z$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the code]

Is there any way to change the size of the xits font only, so it has the same size as the Tex Gyre Adventor font ?

Thank you,
Régis

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, I found the solution on this very site : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210074/63033

I post it here in case anyone is interested :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
%\setmathfont{xits-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=1.2]{xits-math}
\setmathfont[range=up/{num}]{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\begin{document}
In text mode: 3z

In math mode: $3z$.
\end{document}
```

I just had to had the `Scale` parameter to `\setmathfont{xits-math}`.

Comment: Better yet, add `\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase }` and then load the main font with `[Scale=1.0]`. Then you don’t need to guesstimate the correct scaling. You can load a font with `[Scale=MatchUppercase]` if you’ll be using it for things like numbers or uppercase letters.